# javascript checkbox select all, unselect all, invert selection

Tags: javascript, checkbox, action

I meet a problem with a script i'm doing. actually I gave something like that because I'm doing a mail box for my intranet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GereChkbox(conteneur, a_faire) {
var blnEtat=null;
var Chckbox = document.getElementById('box-table-a').firstChild;
    while (Chckbox!=null) {
        if (Chckbox.nodeName=="INPUT")
            if (Chckbox.getAttribute("type")=="checkbox") {
                blnEtat = (a_faire=='0') ? false : (a_faire=='1') ? true : (document.getElementById(Chckbox.getAttribute("id")).checked) ? false : true;
                document.getElementById(Chckbox.getAttribute("id")).checked=blnEtat;
            }
        Chckbox = Chckbox.nextSibling;
    }
}
</script><form>
<table width="100%" border="0" id='box-table-a'>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" width="15%"><strong>Exp&eacute;diteur</strong></th>
    <th scope="col" width="60%"><strong>Message</strong></th>
    <th scope="col" width="10%"><strong>Date</strong></th>
    <th scope="col" width="15%"><strong>Actions</strong></th>
  </tr><?php $sql="SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `id_destinataire`='".$_SESSION['login']."' AND `trash`='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$premiereEntree.", ".$messagesParPage."" ;
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(__LINE__.mysql_error().$sql);
$i=0; 
while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {                                                ?>
<tr>
<td align="left"><?php $req="SELECT * FROM `gestionnaire` WHERE `login`='".$data['id_expediteur']."'";
$result2=mysql_query($req) or die(__LINE__.mysql_error().$req);
$expediteur=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);  ?><img src="<?php if (!empty($expediteur['urlavatar'])) {echo $expediteur['urlavatar']; } else {echo "images/noAvatar.gif" ;} ; ?>" width="50px" height="50px" /><br /><?php echo $expediteur['nom'].' '.$expediteur['prenom'] ; ?></td>
<td><?php if($data['lu']=='0') { echo '<p align="left"><img src="images/Gnome-Mail-Unread-32.png" width="24px" height="24px" /><strong>  '.$data['titre'].'</strong></p>';
$nbChar = 150; // Nb. de caractères sans '...'

if(strlen($data['message']) >= $nbChar)
    $message = substr($data['message'], 0, $nbChar).' [...]';

echo '<p align="left"><i>'.$message.'</i></p>';
}
else { echo '<p align="left"><img src="images/Gnome-Emblem-Mail-32.png" width="24px" height="24px" /><strong>  '.$data['titre'].'</strong></p>';
$nbChar = 150; // Nb. de caractères sans '...'

if(strlen($data['message']) >= $nbChar)
    $message = substr($data['message'], 0, $nbChar).' [...]';

echo '<p align="left"><i>'.$message.'</i></p>';} ;
?></td>
<td><?php echo  date('d-m-Y H:i',strtotime($data["date"])) ; ?></td>
<td><a href="index.php?p=liremessage&amp;id=<?php echo $data['id'] ; ?>"><img src="images/email_open.png" alt="Lire le message" width="24px" height="24px" border="0"  /></a> <img src="images/Gnome-Mail-Forward-32.png" alt="Transf&eacute;rer le message" width="24px" height="24px" border="0"  /> <a href="deletemessage.page?id=<?php echo $data['id'] ; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Voulez vous vraiment supprimer ce message?')"><img src="images/mail-trash.png" alt="Supprimer ce message" width="24px" height="24px" border="0"  /></a> <input type="checkbox" name="action[<?php echo ++$i; ?>]" id="checkbox<?php echo $i; ?>"  /></td>
</tr>
<?php } ; ?>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Actions: <input type="button" value="Tout cocher" onClick="GereChkbox('div_chck','1');">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Tout d&eacute;cocher" onClick="GereChkbox('div_chck','0');">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Inverser la s&eacute;lection" onClick="GereChkbox('div_chck','2');"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

In fact it does not really work because of the script and I have no error messages in the console.

Thank you verry much in advance for your help.

Kind regards.

Comment: Is the question just what it says in the title? If so, why do we need all of the PHP? Perhaps strip down your example a little.

Comment: this php it is because i work with a databse to get some element from this database because it looks like an intranet message inbox like outlook but for the intranet without any mail adrress...in fact I have a script for make select all, or unselect messages or invert the selection, by javascript, the thing is that it does not work, and i do not understand why because i have no error in the console

Comment: Is there something relevant in the PHP or can it be ignored? And if can be ignore, can't it be deleted from the question?

Comment: no the php just display the information from the database it looks like that when work with php is done http://hpics.li/1fc45d8 i also use php to display an other id for the checkbox with +i and ++$i for all the loop using while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, here's a function that toggles / checks / unchecks any checkboxes given to it:

```
function changeCheckboxes(list, value){
    for(var i = list.length - 1 ; i >=0 ; i--){
        list[i].checked = (typeof value === 'boolean') ? value : !list[i].checked ;
   }
}
```

It accepts a nodelist or array of checkboxes as the first parameter. Use it as follows...

### Toggle Checkboxes:

`changeCheckboxes(allCheckboxes);`

### Check Checkboxes:

`changeCheckboxes(allCheckboxes, true);`

### Uncheck Checkboxes:

`changeCheckboxes(allCheckboxes, false);`

To get allCheckboxes, you can do this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var allCheckboxes = [] ;
    for (var j = inputs.length-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--){
        if (inputs[j].type === 'checkbox'){
        allCheckboxes.push(inputs[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you verry much for the help, but i'm still don't know why my first script did not work previously

Comment: Please use == instead of = for comparison.